# Rails 4: Non-RESTful path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Users model.
Users are capable of having 0+ attributes.
These Users are typically viewed from the index.
Users with 0 attributes, have nothing noted next to their name.
Users with > 0 attributes, have a number noted next to their name. Hover over to be shown all attributes on this user.

I would like to create a page that lists only users who have attributes and then lists each attribute.

I can't think of what my path would be to create something like this. Should it be almost like a static page sort of deal, or should I put this in the Users controller with everything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# UsersController
def index
  @users = User.all  # User.scoped for Rails < 4
  @users = @users.where(...attributes logic...)  if params[:with_attributes]
```

Then you can either use a URL/FORM param or special route to set the :with_attributes param. Using the URL param seems the most RESTFUL.

Navigate to `/users?with_attributes=true`

OR

```
# routes.rb
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'with_attributes' => 'users#index', :with_attributes => true  # :requirements => {:with_attributes => true} for Rails < 4 ???
  end
end
```

And navigate to `/users/with_attributes`.

### EDIT

The `:with_attributes => true` option in the route definition will be added to the request parameters, so you can test for it in your controllers and views using `params[:with_attributes]`.

Comment: I marked your solution as the answer (using the second option), but I have question in trying to understand what's going on. I following everything prior to `:with_attributes => true`. What precisely is this saying? I'm unable to find this information from the rails routing article I'm looking at.     
Additionally, I'm using the `only:` option on my users resource already, how do I add `with_attributes` to this?

Comment: @user2402831 sorry, I did not explain that well. The `:with_attributes => true` option will simply be added to the params when a request matches the route in my example. I've updated the answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Something maybe like this.

In routes.rb

```
get 'users/with_attributes' => 'users#with_attributes', as: :users_with_attributes
```

In controller

```
def with_attributes
    @users = User.where(....
end
```

in view

```
= link_to 'Users with attributes', users_with_attributes_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Your paths would just route to specific actions, so your goal is really to get the different actions to show as required:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   collection do
       get :with_attribute
       get :without_attribute
   end
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def with_attribute
    @users = User.where(attribute: true)
end

def without_attribute
    @users = User.where(...)
end
```